# Android like status bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there's a jquery plugin or something similar where I can create an android like notication bar, where you drag the the statusbar down to see notifications, using just html and js?

Couldn't find anything while searching online.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [this](http://www.merulasoft.nl/2011/07/23/jquery-ui-statusbar/) you mean?

Comment: This one is pretty sweet, making it dragable would make it awesome!

Comment: Yes that looks good! However it does not seem to work on the iPhone.