# how to create a simple bar just like android notification bar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android like status bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196327/android-like-status-bar)

I want some help here :

I want to create an "**android style notification bar**" which we have it in our **smart phones** that can be dragged down and then sent up back any time . But it is nothing related to **android**
On dragging i want a particular page to load say "x.php" . I think jquery will solve the issue but how !

Any help will be appreciated . 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: You could make an element draggable with jQuery? Then listen for where it is?

Comment: I tried to use jquery draggable but could'nt succeed

Comment: @navnav : i did'nt ask you to code for me . I just wanted some sort of help as in if any jquery plugin is available . I did lot of googling but could'nt find anything appropriate

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Well, here is my advice; the whole slider thing is cool on touch screens, but wont be so nice on computers. Who likes sliding their mouse up and down the page? Certainly not me. I'm not trying to put you off or anything, but just think about that.